# ADF passing blank parameters to Databricks as double quotes

Tags: azure-data-factory, databricks, linked-service

I'm using ADF to call Databricks notebooks via linked service.

When ADF passes parameters as blank (either leaving the input box as blank or typing ""), Databricks notebooks widgets read it as two double quotes (a string of "")

As in the image below both params would be read as double quotes in the Databricks notebook. (using `dbutils.widgets.get()`)

[image]

To my knowledge, one way to handle this issue is to add handling code in the notebook after reading the widgets input. However, I'm wondering if there's something I've missed, or is there is any other ways around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Parameters` if you give blank value it takes value
from `Default value` whatever you have given earlier.
So, check the `Default value` you given.

[image]

Below is the input passed when I run the notebook with blank values.

[image]

and

[image]

If you observe clearly in this input even though i did not give quotes it is added, because the parameter is of type `String` whatever you pass it is enclosed by quotes automatically.

The same is with you when passed double quotes.

[image]

Inputs:

[image]

So, when these inputs sent to databricks it will take it with double quotes.

And below is the run details in databricks and run output in adf.

[image]

and
[image]

So, do `json.loads` for parameter whichever having double quotes.

Below is the parameter i sent.

[image]

and while sending back to adf do `json.dumps` on data.

```
import json
x = json.loads(dbutils.widgets.get("name"))
y = json.loads(dbutils.widgets.get("id"))
dt = x+" "+y
dt = json.dumps(dt)
dbutils.notebook.exit(dt)
```

Output in databricks

[image]

My suggestion is send the text directly without double quotes for `String` type or do a `json.loads()` in notebook.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation. In my case, the problem exists when I try to send blank (that is, no character at all). So, your first solution (i.e., sending the text directly without double quotes) might not be applicable. I dealt with the problem by handling the quotes sent manually, so as you suggest json.loads() is a great alternative. Thank you for suggesting!

Comment: I also tried leaving the parameter as blank (not inputting any character in ADF). However, the ADF will trigger an error saying "Could not parse request object: Expected both 'key' and 'value' to be set on elements in the field 'base_parameters'
 at [Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 1, column: 889]
 at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@4b252d16; line: 1, column: 889]." So I think the only way to pass blank is to pass it as something like "" and handle them in Databricks manaully, or using json.loads().

Comment: Yes. Atleast you need to specify random value in pipeline parameters which you will not use. And you can set blank value while running pipeline.

Comment: hm, what do you mean by I can set blank value while running pipeline?

Comment: You can set blank value while triggering the pipeline only when you have given default value to that parameter. And it takes default value automatically. See the above solution given.

Comment: Yes, you're right on your answer. ADF takes the default value if we set blank while triggering. BUT, Let's say if I wanted to send **blank** to Databricks, I'd set the default value as blank and also set the value when debug/trigger as blank. This would result in an error I pasted in the comment above. That's what I meant in the last comment.

Comment: No. if you want to send **blank** value to databricks you need to give parameter as `""`
and load using json. This will take blank value. But remember any one of the value should be passed either a default or while debug or trigger.

Comment: Yep that clears all the doubts. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the ADF passes the parameter as a null value and the Databricks's widget doesn't accept null values only empty strings.

To resolve this issue, you can treat the pipeline parameter before send to the "Base Parameter" at Settings in the Databricks activity to send empty strings to the Databricks Widgets instead of null values.

An example:

```
@if(empty(pipeline().parameters.start_date), '', pipeline().parameters.start_date)
```

This way, if the parameter `start_date` is empty, ADF will send an empty string instead of a null value.

In Databricks you can simple do this:

```
start_date = dbutils.widgets.get('start_date')
if start_date:
   ## any code here
```